# An error occurred while converting the C extension file( test1.c ) compiled by the pro*c file into a wasm file through Emscripten

Tags: oracle, webassembly, porting, emscripten, proc

An error occurred while converting the C extension file( test1.c ) compiled by the pro*c file into a wasm file through Emscripten.

I am using Emscripten to convert legacy code to WebAssembly's WASM file. After compiling the Pro*C file into a .C file, converting it using Emscipten, the following error occurred.
Thank you in advance.

The following is the output of the execution command and errors.

```
D:\C-connection\FASSDB>emcc test1.c -s WASM=1 -s -o public/test.js
test1.c:117:8: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
extern sqlcxt ( void **, unsigned int *,
~~~~~~ ^
int
test1.c:119:8: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
extern sqlcx2t( void **, unsigned int *,
~~~~~~ ^
int
test1.c:121:8: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
extern sqlbuft( void **, char * );
~~~~~~ ^
int
test1.c:122:8: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
extern sqlgs2t( void **, char * );
~~~~~~ ^
int
test1.c:123:8: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
extern sqlorat( void **, unsigned int *, void * );
~~~~~~ ^
int
5 errors generated.
emcc: error: 'D:/C-connection/emsdk/upstream/bin\clang.exe -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -fvisibility=default -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr -DEMSCRIPTEN -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major__=3 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=1 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=18 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -ID:\C-connection\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\include\SDL --sysroot=D:\C-connection\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include\compat test1.c -c -o C:\Users\REALHO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_337o8xxh\test1_0.o' failed (returned 1)
```

The following is a Pro*C file before compiling into *.c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca.h;
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    varchar id[50];
    varchar password[50];
    varchar tns[50];
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    memset(&id, 0x00, sizeof(id));
    memset(&password, 0x00, sizeof(password));
    memset(&tns, 0x00, sizeof(tns));

    strcpy((char*)id.arr, "dbid");
    strcpy((char*)password.arr, "dbpassword");
    strcpy((char*)tns.arr, "orcl");

    id.len = strlen((char*)id.arr);
    password.len = strlen((char*)password.arr);
    tns.len = strlen((char*)tns.arr);

    // EXEC SQL CONNECT :id IDENTIFIED BY :password ;
    EXEC SQL CONNECT :id IDENTIFIED BY :password USING :tns ;
    if(sqlca.sqlcode < 0) {
        printf("connect error\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("connect success\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Are you including all the Oracle precompiler header files, as you would if you were compiling with gcc?

Comment: tripleee > yes i changed that part